# android memory management (Heap Size)

Tags: android

i am developing one application related to graphics, in this application i am using 
  lots of images and drawing on it.and all activities are running until my flow does not
  get completed.so what should i do for assign large heap size to run smoothly my 
  application. Or any other way to run application smoothly .. i have no idea about 
  memory management right now . i am using only BitmapDrawable to display images and also 
  system.gc() to garbage collection . also use this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalizersOnExit(true);
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

can anybody help me .. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not allow you to adjust your heap size for Java code—you’re stuck with a value of about 20MB (perhaps more on newer devices). Always remember to recycle your bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Java weak references so that these images are automatically garbage collected? [This](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) blog post explains that well. Also, you can use Guava Collections [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) for the images.

Comment: can u give me some example for the same

Answer (score 1):

It not possible to increase Heap Size.Its fixed.But you an do some calculation to remove some waste of memory.

1) If you are using Bitmap then recycle it using bitmap.recycle() when it use became over, this will be garbage collected.

2)Try to remove unnecessary reference from your object if there is no use of them.

3)Try to use Local Variable and avoid Static function and variable

Hope it help you :)